# Installing Canon MG2555 this happend:

Tags: drivers, printer

[image]

I'm not a big linux wizzard. To me it looks like the installation script wants me to perform the command by hand because it cannot find the canonmg2500.ppd file. Which makes total sense as it is not within the driver files that are downloaded. So entering the command by hand will have the same result.

How do i get this printer to work ? It is not automatically detected, even if the drivers are installed. (common and printer specific .deb files are installed via package manager.